# How do I get code coverage from XSpec

Tags: java, xslt, xspec

I am using XSpec at work for XSL unit tests.  I see XSpec as a coverage option but I cannot get it to work.  I get this error:

"Transformation failed: Failed to load com.jenitennison.xslt.tests.XSLTCoverageTr
aceListener

Testing with SAXON 9.1.0.7"

I am having a tough time finding recent information about XSpec.  Can any one point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this already applies for saxon 9.1, just found that newer saxon versions aren't compatible with xspec, but it seems to be possible to get it working with some adjustments. Found here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/xspec-users/VRlCTR5KvIU

Comment: Yeah, I saw that thread.  I tried the tweaks mentioned without luck.  I was able to compile the Java and edit the batch file, but I still get the same error.  Seems like that Google group is deserted.  I've posted twice this week and I don't think the posts have even been approved.

Answer (score 0):

Code coverage in XSpec is currently not working. I posted a pull request that should fix the code coverage: https://github.com/expath/xspec/pull/80. If you want to fix it in your version of XSpec before the next release, look at the commit changes in files xspec.sh and XSLTCoverageTraceListener.java (see https://github.com/expath/xspec/pull/80/files).

Note that code coverage now works only with SaxonEE and SaxonPE (not Saxon HE) as the Java class requires extension functions which are only available with these two versions of Saxon.